# Order column by the last letter in the records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table named `seat` which contains the following records :

```
+----+------+
| ID | Seat |
+----+------+
| 1  | 1a   |
+----+------+
| 2  | 1b   |
+----+------+
| 3  | 2a   |      
+----+------+
| 4  | 2b   |  
+----+------+
| 5  | 3a   |  
+----+------+
| 6  | 3b   |  
+----+------+
| 7  | 4a   |  
+----+------+
| 8  | 4b   |  
+----+------+
| 9  | 10a  |  
+----+------+
| 10 | 10b  |  
+----+------+
| 11 | 11a  |  
+----+------+
| 12 | 11b  |  
+----+------+
| 13 | 12a  |  
+----+------+
| 14 | 12b  |  
+----+------+
```

I want to order the result based on the last character of the second column `seat` so my table shows :

```
+----+------+
| ID | Seat |
+----+------+
| 1  | 1a   |
+----+------+
| 3  | 2a   |      
+----+------+
| 5  | 3a   |  
+----+------+
| 7  | 4a   |  
+----+------+
| 9  | 10a  |
+----+------+
| 11 | 11a  |  
+----+------+
| 13 | 12a  |  
+----+------+
| 2  | 1b   |  
+----+------+
| 4  | 2b   |
+----+------+
| 6  | 3b   |      
+----+------+
| 8  | 4b   |  
+----+------+
| 10 | 10b  |  
+----+------+
| 12 | 11b  |  
+----+------+
| 14 | 12b  |  
+----+------+
```

How can I achieve that result? what functions I should use ?

Comment: This shows a flaw in the database design. You are interested in the separate information "row" (1,2,3,...) and "seat in the row" (a,b), but instead you store the combined values leading to problems now. So the best answer is probably: Don't try to find a query for this, but change your data model instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about it. Could you point me to a better model?

Comment: `id` + `seat_row` + `seat_place` instead of `id` + `seat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you can use [`right`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_right) to order by the last value(*i.e. sign*) and then cast the whole string to unsigned (*i.e., in MySQL, `11a` is converted to `11`*):

```
order by right(`seat`, 1), cast(`seat` as unsigned)
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/426cb/5)

Comment: thanks, it worked for a while. The problem comes when I insert tens values such as `10a`, `10b`, `11a`, `11b` mixed with above values. The result goes horribly wrong

Comment: @AnggieAriWidhia: Updated

Comment: solved, I use this `SELECT * FROM `bus` ORDER BY RIGHT(seat, 1), CAST(seat AS unsigned)`. First I order the column based on the last letter of the records, then order them numerically.